# Where to put Session_OnStart in asp.net razor c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have a website built by using ASP.NET razor c# in VS 2015, but not MVC. I want to implement the `Session_OnStart` function, but all of the documentation I have been able to find says to put in in the `Global.aspx` file. However, this is not a classic asp.net application, so there are not `aspx` files, only `cshtml` files. The main file is `_Default.cshtml`. I tried putting in at the end of the `_Default.cshtml` file, which compiled correctly, but did not get called whne the website started.

Where do I put this function?

Comment: I hope you are talking about Global.asax. You can always added it.

Comment: Thanks.  I had just looked at another comment and it showed how to add the global.asax. I did and that solved the problem. Somehow I had it in my head that *.asax and *.cshtml are incompatible. Don't know how I go that.

Comment: Great you are able to resolve it :)